# Find element in div that's not a child

Tags: jquery, html

Trying to create a script that does some css to the parent of this element, but i first need to filter/check the button elements title. Bootstrap changes the title of the button element depending on the select element option chosen. I don't think I can choose .parent() or .children() because they aren't parents or children of each other. Tried .closest() but no dice the way I have it set up.

When I console log businessCheck it returns undefined.

```
 var businessCheck = $('#businessMarkets').closest("button").prop("title");
 console.log(businessCheck)

<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control">
   <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="businessMarkets" title="Business 
   Markets Served*">
   </button>

   <div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox">
   </div>

   <select id="businessMarkets">
     <option value="">Title</option>
     <option value="" disabled="" selected="false" style="display: none;" id="businessMarkets- 
     Placeholder">Business Markets Served*</option>
   </select>
</div>

<button id="toSlide-3"></button>


<script>
function check_BusinessMarket() {
 var businessCheck = 
 $('#businessMarkets').closest("button").prop("title");
 console.log(businessCheck)

$('#toSlide-3').on('click', function (event) {
  check_BusinessMarket()
})

</script>
```

Comment: *does some css to the parent of this element*, you are gonna have to explain it better. what elements are involved? should it happen on click? on change?

Comment: I can do all that. All I'm looking for is to create a variable that logs the button's title element on click. I'll add the script.

Comment: Try this: `$('#businessMarkets').parent().find('button').attr("title");` or `$('#businessMarkets').siblings('button').attr("title");` [jQuery `.siblings()`](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/)

Comment: I think that did it. So it went to the parent element... then traversed to find the button...then the title attribute?

Comment: Yes. You could also use `.closest()` rather than `.parent()`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The button is a sibling of the select menu, therefore you can traverse to it using the [siblings](https://api.jquery.com/siblings/) method.

```js
var title = $('#businessMarkets').siblings("button").prop("title");

console.log(title);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group bootstrap-select form-control">
   <button type="button" data-toggle="dropdown" data-id="businessMarkets" title="Business Markets Served*">
   </button>

   <div class="dropdown-menu open" role="combobox">
   </div>

   <select id="businessMarkets">
     <option value="">Title</option>
     <option value="" disabled="" selected="false" style="display: none;" id="businessMarkets- 
     Placeholder">Business Markets Served*</option>
   </select>
</div>
```